# how to create events on dynamic `textboxes`

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I managed to create `textboxes` that are created at runtime on every button click.  I want the text from `textboxes` to disappear when I click on them. I know how to create events, but not for dynamically created textboxes.

How would I wire this up to my new textboxes?

```
private void buttonClear_Text(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myText.Text = "";
}
```

Comment: "I want the text from textboxes to disappear when I click on them" Doesn't sound like a good UI design to me...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is how you assign the event handler for every newly created textbox :

```
myTextbox.Click  += new System.EventHandler(buttonClear_Text);
```

Answer (score 5):

The sender parameter here should be the textbox which sent the even you will need to cast it to the correct control type and set the text as normal

```
if (sender is TextBox) {
     ((TextBox)sender).Text = "";
}
```

To register the event to the textbox

```
myText.Click  += new System.EventHandler(buttonClear_Text);
```

Comment: THis answer shows how you will handle the event, and misses the point to create the even. After your code to create the dynamic TextBox, you should use the newly created instance to attach it to the event handler.

Comment: @Dhawalk Just add the event handler at the same place you are creating the textbox.

Answer (score 2):

Your question isn't very clear, but I suspect you just need to use the `sender` parameter:

```
private void buttonClear_Text(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox textBox = (TextBox) sender;
    textBox.Text = "";
}
```

(The name of the method isn't particularly clear here, but as the question isn't either, I wasn't able to suggest a better one...)

Answer (score 1):

when you create the textBoxObj:

```
RoutedEventHandler reh = new RoutedEventHandler(buttonClear_Text);
textBoxObj.Click += reh;
```

and I think (not 100% sure) you have to change the listener to

```
private void buttonClear_Text(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess the OP wants to clear all the text from the created `textBoxes`

```
private void buttonClear_Text(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  ClearSpace(this);
}

public static void ClearSpace(Control control)
{
    foreach (var c in control.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
    {
        (c).Clear();
        if (c.HasChildren)
            ClearSpace(c);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job  :

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = new Button();
        this.Controls.Add(btn);

        // adtionally set the button location & position

        //register the click handler
        btn.Click += OnClickOfDynamicButton;
    }

    private void OnClickOfDynamicButton(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        //since you dont not need to know which of the created button is click, you just need the text to be ""
        ((Button) sender).Text = string.Empty;
    }
```